# "Cannot change a part of an array" error with UNIQUE forumula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using a formula based on `=UNIQUE(FILTER(....))`.

I use the result list to determine a lot of other columns. The last one is the score.

I'm trying to sort the score column (to sort all the table) by DESCENDING score.

However I'm facing following issue : "You cannot change part of an array".

It is not possible to sort when `=UNIQUE(FILTER(....))` is used ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Do you have a simple set of data to work with. Including your desired result? But, yes it's possible through `SORTBY()` for example.

Comment: Put some sample data. You can use `SORT()` function to sort data.

Comment: To use SORT() I need to do it in another range correct ? I cannot sort directly on the data, right ? Thanks.

Comment: As mentioned before, that's perfectly possible using `SORTBY()` or `SORT()`. Without a proper set of sample data to show what it is you are doing there is not much else to say I'm afraid.